# Flink FileProcessingMode puzzling

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I don't understand StreamExecutionEnvironment.readFile method. The FileProcessingMode has 2 options: PROCESS_ONCE and PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY. If we choose the former, it just processes the file once and exits  after execute(). If we choose the latter, even we just append some lines to the file, it will process the whole file again (adding all, e.g., the count of each word on top of last processing). I would expect that is something like 'tail', it only reads the more things from the "stream" rather than reading from beginning again and again.  I am lost of this "streaming". Could anybody explain why we don't have the 'tail' like thing to process the file just 'once' and continue while the file is being appended more texts like log files?

Answer (score 0):

With PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, Flink keeps a timestamp as state, and ingests any files that are newer than the timestamp. Your observations are accurate, but there is a case where this works well. If you use PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY with a directory, rather than a file, and periodically move files into that directory when they are complete and ready to be processed, then you can get "exactly once" behavior.